# Android how to perform Any ui action from SyncAdapter?

Tags: android, synchronization

I have completed all operation related to syncAdapter but now i m stuck on one minor issue

*Auth Token*

After 2hr my token just expired and then i need to show user a dialog to enter his password again so that he can renew his token.

```
AccountManager.get(getContext()).getAuthToken(account, LoginActivity.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null, false, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

            @Override
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {
                try {
                    arg0.getResult();
                } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, null);
```

I m running this on onPerformSync but this is not opening an activity.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to doing this

1) in your `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter` implementation of overridden `onPerformSync` method you need to

- Get the authcode from the `AccountManager` using method `blockingGetAuthToken()`
- Try to use the authcode to perform your sync processes (i.e. web service call or whatever you use it for)
- If the previous step failed because authcode has expired (e.g. your web serivce returns some kind of authcode expired message) then you need to invalidate the authcode via the `AccountManager` using method `invalidateAuthToken()`

2) in your `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` implementation of overridden `getAuthToken()` method

- Use the `AccountManager` to retrieve the password that the user last provided and try to get a new authcode from your web service using those credentials.
- If the previous step failed then add an intent to open your login activity to the bundle that is returned from the `getAuthToken()` method. **This will cause the login screen to display**

Example

```
@Override
public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse oResponse, Account oAccount, String strAuthTokenType, Bundle options) 
          throws NetworkErrorException {

    // Validate the authentication type         
    if (!strAuthTokenType.equals("TODO: your auth token type URL here")) 
    {
        final Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE, "invalid authTokenType");
        return result;
    }

    // Try to get the password already stored in account manger, if there is one
    final AccountManager oAccountManager = AccountManager.get(moContext);
    final String strPassword = oAccountManager.getPassword(oAccount);
    if (strPassword != null) 
    {   
        // TODO: Call the authentication web service method to get a fresh authcode
        // Pass the strPassword and oAccount.name
        Boolean blnVerified = //TODO: were the username + password authenticated?
        String strNewAuthCode = //TODO: the new authcode returned by your authentication web service

        // If it worked then return the result
        if (blnVerified) 
        {
            final Bundle result = new Bundle();
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, oAccount.name);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, "TODO: your account type URI here");
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, strNewAuthCode);
            return result;
        }
    }

    // Password is missing or incorrect. Start the activity to ask user to provide the missing credentials.
    // Open a UI form to get the user to input their username and password again
    final Intent oIntent = new Intent(moContext, frmAccount_Auth.class);
    oIntent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, oResponse);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, oIntent);
    return bundle;
}
```